# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre success y done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Bueno tengo una linea de código en ajax la cual no se si es mejor usar `success` o `done` No comprendo la diferencia entre estos términos pero al final los 2 hacen lo mismo o yo entiendo mal el concepto.

```
    $('#main form').on('submit', function () {

       // var act = $('#main form').attr('action');
       // var met = $('#main form').attr('method');
        var titulo = $('#titulo').val();
        var dcorta = $('#dcorta').val();
        var dlarga = $('#dlarga').val();
        var importancia = $('#importancia').val();


        $.ajax({
            url: '/noticiasfinal/model/guardar_noticia.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {titulo:titulo,dcorta:dcorta,dlarga:dlarga,importancia:importancia},
            succes: function(){
                window.location.assign('/?view=noticias'+'&id='+id)
            }
        });
    })

;
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Aunque `success` ha sido la forma tradicional de la devolución de llamada de éxito en jQuery, sin embargo, desde la implementación de `$.Deferreds` y `callbacks` más sofisticados, `done` es la forma preferida de implementar callbacks de éxito.

En la documentación de jQuery leemos lo siguiente:

> **Aviso de inhabilitación**: Las devoluciones de llamada `jqXHR.success
>   ()`, `jqXHR.error ()` y `jqXHR.complete ()` se eliminan a partir de
>   jQuery 3.0. Puede utilizar `jqXHR.done ()`, `jqXHR.fail ()` y
>   `jqXHR.always ()` en su lugar.

Esto quiere decir que desde jQuery 3 se recomienda usar `done`.

#### ¿Por qué usar `done` ?

Porque los objetos jqXHR devueltos por `$ .ajax ()` a partir de jQuery 1.5 implementan la interfaz Promise, dándoles todas las propiedades, métodos y comportamiento de una Promise (vea el objeto [Diferido](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) para más información). Estos métodos toman uno o más argumentos de función que se llaman cuando finaliza la solicitud `$ .ajax ()`. Esto permite asignar varias devoluciones de llamada en una sola solicitud e incluso asignar devoluciones de llamada después de que la solicitud se haya completado. (Si la solicitud ya está completa, la devolución de llamada se disparará inmediatamente.)

Los métodos Promise disponibles del objeto jqXHR incluyen:

- `jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});`
  Una construcción alternativa a la opción de devolución de llamada de éxito, consulte [`deferred.done ()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) para detalles de implementación.
- `jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});`
  Una construcción alternativa a la opción de devolución de llamada de error, el método `.fail ()` sustituye al método .error () obsoleto. Consulte [`deferred.fail ()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) para obtener detalles sobre la implementación.
- `jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) { });` (agregado en jQuery 1.6)
  Una construcción alternativa a la opción de devolución de llamada completa, el método `.always ()` sustituye al método obsoleto `.complete ()`.

En respuesta a una solicitud satisfactoria, los argumentos de la función son los mismos que los de `.done ()`: data, textStatus y el objeto jqXHR. Para las solicitudes con error, los argumentos son los mismos que los de `.fail ()`: el objeto jqXHR, textStatus y errorThrown. Consulte [deferred.always ()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) para obtener detalles sobre la implementación.

- `jqXHR.then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {}, function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});`
  Incorpora la funcionalidad de los métodos `.done ()` y `.fail ()`, permitiendo (a partir de jQuery 1.8) que la Promesa subyacente sea manipulada. Consulte [`deferred.then ()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) para obtener detalles sobre la implementación.

Lo bueno de `done` es que el valor de retorno de `$.ajax` es ahora una promesa diferida que puede estar vinculado a cualquier otro lugar en su aplicación. Así que digamos que desea hacer esta llamada ajax desde unos pocos lugares diferentes. En lugar de pasar su función de éxito como una opción a la función que hace esta llamada ajax, sólo puede tener la función de retorno `$.ajax`  y vincular sus devoluciones de llamada con `done`, `fail`, `then`, o lo que sea. Ten en cuenta que siempre es una devolución de llamada que se ejecutará si la solicitud tiene éxito o falla. `done` sólo se activará cuando la petición ajax sea exitosa.

Ejemplo completo usando lo dicho anteriormente:

```
// Se asignan manejadores inmediatamente después de hacer la petición
// y se recuerda el objeto jqXHR  para esta petición
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "èxito" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "completado" );
  });

// Hacer otra cosa aquí ...

// Asignar otra función de completado para la petición de más arriba
jqxhr.always(function() {
  alert( "completado segundo" );
});
```

Otro ejemplo:

```
function xhr_get(url) {

  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: mostrarImagenCargando
  })
  .always(function() {
    // Por ejemplo removemos la imagen "cargando..."
  })
  .fail(function() {
    // Manejar errores
  });

}

xhr_get('/index').done(function(data) {
  // Hacer algo con data
});

xhr_get('/id').done(function(data) {
  // hacer algo con el id de data
});
```

Un beneficio importante de esto en términos de mantenimiento es que ha envuelto su mecanismo ajax en una función específica de la aplicación. Si decides que necesitas tu llamada `$.ajax` para operar de manera diferente en el futuro, o usas un método diferente de ajax, o te alejas de jQuery, solo tienes que cambiar la definición de `xhr_get` (estar seguro de devolver una promesa o al menos un método `done`, en el caso del ejemplo anterior). Todas las demás referencias a lo largo de la aplicación pueden seguir siendo las mismas.

Hay muchas más cosas (mucho más frescas) que puedes hacer con `$.Deferred,` una de las cuales es usar `pipe` (o mejor `then`) para activar un error en un error reportado por el servidor, incluso cuando la solicitud `$.ajax` tiene éxito. 
Por ejemplo:

```
function xhr_get(url) {

  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json'
  })
  .pipe(function(data) {
    return data.responseCode != 200 ?
      $.Deferred().reject( data ) :
      data;
  })
  .fail(function(data) {
    if ( data.responseCode )
      console.log( data.responseCode );
  });
}

xhr_get('/index').done(function(data) {
  // No funcionará si el json retornado desde ajax no tiene el código de respuesta 200
});
```

---

Fuentes:

- [Documentación de jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- [jQuery.ajax handling continue responses: “success:” vs “.done”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8840315/5587982)

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69272/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-success-y-done).

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es qué estructura debe tener la respuesta del servidor (un archivo php en mi caso), para que esa respuesta vaya a .done o .fail. O sea, como escribo el código de mi json_encode()  que envío de vuelta desde mi php.

Comment: @RaúlSoriaOrtiz he puesto un ejemplo en tu pregunta, puedes consultar allí.

Answer (score 1):

> No comprendo la diferencia entre estos términos

- `success`, es la opción para obtener el resultado del `ajax` bajo el patrón de programación con [`callbacks`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)
- `done`, es la opción para obtener el resultado del `ajax` bajo el patrón de programación con [`deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) (o [`promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise))

> al final los 2 hacen lo mismo o yo entiendo mal el concepto.

Si con *"al final los 2 hacen lo mismo"*, te refieres a que obtienes el resultado esperado, la respuesta es **SI**, solo que usando distintos patrones.

Si te decides por usar `done`, entonces obtienes ["*los beneficios*" que brindan las `promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usar_promesas)

Más info:

- [Promesas de JavaScript: introducción](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises)