# Error ejecucion javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código que realiza una petición a un WS por jquery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calling Web Service from jQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CallWebService(){ 

                $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST", 
                url: "urldelWS",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: "{parámetros de la petición}", 
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                success: function (data){}, 
                error: function (data){} 
                 }); 

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>
        Calling Web Services with jQuery/AJAX
    </h3>
    <input type="submit" onclick="CallWebService()" value="Call web service"  />
</body>
</html>
```

Mi problema es que cuando presiono el botón, en la consola del navegador me muestra el siguiente error:

> SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined

Alguna idea de donde esta el error.

Comment: serciorate que te carga bien el jquery

Comment: como puedo cerciorarme?

Comment: Puede ser un problema del DOM, que no esté listo cuando es invocado el código jQuery. Rodea tu código por: `$(function() {         function CallWebService(){ 
// resto del código
} });` También **pon https:// en lugar de http://  en la url de la librería jQuery** y de paso usa una librería más actualizada, ya está en su versión 3: **`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`**

Comment: con el inspector de codigo del navegador en la pestaña red o network si esta en ingles.prove el ejemplo que pones solo cambiando la url y me funciono, la maquina donde pruebas esto debe estar conectada a internet.Otra prueba que puedes hacer es copiar esto direccion `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js` en una pestaña y ver si carga.

Comment: Al rodear mi código con la sintaxis que me indicaron me arroja el siguiente error:  SCRIPT5009: 'CallWebService' is undefined

Comment: Al insertar la url de ajax en el navegador, si me dirige a la librería

Comment: Observa el código como está en la respuesta y pruébalo así. Comenta el resultado.

Comment: Realize las modificaciones al pie de la letra y me arroja el siguiente error: SCRIPT5009: 'CallWebService' is undefined

Comment: He modificado un poco el código, revisa la respuesta editada. Lo he probado y me funciona.

Comment: Realicé las modificaciones mencionadas y ahora no hace nada, y cuando le doy refrescar a la página me arroja el error: SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined

Comment: Si has modificado tal y como aparece **ahora** en la respuesta y no funciona, el problema debe estar en otra parte, no en el código. Revisa la consola de javascript a ver si da alguna pista de lo que podría estar pasando.

Comment: Cuando ejecuto la pagina, en la consola me muestra el siguiente mensaje: JavaScript Console is attached and accepting commands. Después hago click en el botón y no hace nada. Pero si actualizo la página me muestra los siguientes mensajes: HTML1300: Navigation occurred. y después este: SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined

Comment: ¿Qué explorador usas? ¿Puedes probar con otro explorador diferente? ¿No estarás incluyendo la librería jQuery por otra parte? ¿Pusiste la jQuery de `code.jquery.com`?

Comment: Con internet explorer. Ahora intente con Chrome y muestra los siguientes errores: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
send @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4

Comment: Y después me muestra el siguiente: jquery-3.2.1.min.js Failed to load resource
send @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4. Dichos errores me los muestra al hacer click en el botón.

Comment: Si puse el jquery de code.jquery.com

Comment: Ahí si parece funcionar, el aviso de deprecated es debido al uso de `success` al manejar la petición Ajax. Si comentas todo el bloque de petición ajax y pones sólo `alert("prueba");` en las diferentes partes verás que funciona. En cuanto al deprecated, si usas `done` como comento en la **nota**  al final de la respuesta, no te aparecerá el aviso. He leído que IE tiene problemas con el uso asíncrono... habría que controlar la forma en que se incluyen las librerías y archivos js en el código, tomando en cuenta las posibles páginas o archivos incluidos.

Comment: Ok, otro favor, me podrías poner el ejemplo de como utilizar done en lugar de success? Siendo sincero no me queda claro como ponerlo en mi código. Gracias

Comment: Tienes un ejemplo usando `done`. Espero te sirva. Si la respuesta resuelve el problema, puedes marcarla como solución, para que no quede abierta la pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

#### Respuesta editada con algunos cambios:

Veo dos cosas que debes mejorar en el código:

1. La librería jQuery: conviene usar una url que empiece por `https://` y usar una librería más actualizada. Ya la librería va por su versión 3. He optado por la librería de jQuery oficial, la de google me daba un error de url
2. Hay que controlar que el DOM esté listo cuando invocamos nuestro código jQuery, rodeándolo por `$(function() { ... });`:

También, he optado por usar el elemento `button` directamente, escuchando el evento `click` del mismo desde jQuery.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calling Web Service from jQuery</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(function() {
        $( "#btnCallWS" ).click(function() {
        alert("ok");
        myUrl="ruta/archivo.php"; //sustituir por datos reales
        valor="test"; //sustituir por datos reales
        datos={ clave : valor };  //sustituir por datos reales
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: myUrl,
            method: "POST",
            data: datos,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            cache: false,
            async: false
        });

            request.done(function( msg ) {
                alert("Hubo éxito en la petición");
                console.log(msg);
            });

            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                alert( "Hubo un error: " + textStatus );
            });
        });
    });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h3>
        Calling Web Services with jQuery/AJAX
     </h3>
     <button id="btnCallWS">Call Web Service</button>
```

---

**Nota:** Habría más cosas a mejorar en un futuro, como el uso de `done` en lugar de `success` para manejar la respuesta Ajax. Para ello puedes consultar: [¿Cual es la diferencia entre success y done?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/98884/29967)