# Cargar vista en un modal con Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, modal, controller

¡Hola!
Verán... Tengo un dilema con la carga de un archivo (vista) que necesito se habrá en el `body` de un `modal`, ya que, este sera el principio para poder mostrar información mas adelante.
Como tal, tengo lo siguiente.

En mi vista **Listado** *(donde tengo una tabla de valores)* le eh asignado que muestre el botón dinámicamente, el cual lanza un `modal` para que muestre un archivo con valores dinámicamente del ID que halla seleccionado *(Ese es el objetivo)*.
Antes de eso, me eh atorado con siquiera mostrar el archivo que cargara el `modal`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Les muestro 1ro el código del botón:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-view-contrato" value="<?php echo $NewContrato->id_contratos_d;?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_contrato"><span class="fa fa-file-text-o"></span></button>
```

**El codigo del `modal`:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_contrato">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Contrato</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-print"><span class="fa fa-print"> </span> Imprimir</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**El script:**

```
<script >
     $(document).on("click",".btn-view-contrato", function(){
        valor_IDcontrato = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "clientes/Clientes_controller/contrato_view",
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"html",
            data:{id:valor_IDcontrato},
            success:function(data){
                $("#modal_contrato .modal-body").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**¡Ojo!** me asegure de los más lógico que es que la ruta estuviera bien tanto para llamar el controlador y llamar el archivo a cargar.

Y por ultimo, de la función del controlador:

```
   public function contrato_view(){
        $New_id_Contrato = $this->input->post("id");

        $this->load->view("admin/clientes/contrato");
    }
```

Pero no carga la vista y solo aparece en blanco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**NOTA:** Se que hasta el momento no lo estoy pasando información al modal, pero antes que nada **necesito siquiera se muestre hasta este punto la vista que le estoy pasando** (`$this->load->view("admin/clientes/contrato");`) ya que para pasar información perteneciente, me las arreglo pasando un `data` desde un `ARRAY`.

**Muchas gracias por haber leído esto en 1ra instancia :D**

Comment: probaste los nuevos cambios que use?

Comment: En eso estoy, trato de entender lo que esperas que haga, también estoy leyendo mas sobre `done` por lo de `sucess` ya que tengo un ejemplo funcional de `sucess` dentro de de otro proyecto (del cual me estoy basando). Aunque eso si: ya cambia a `done`.

Comment: Entra en consola a network y busca la petición y ve que te está regresando

Comment: en lo que te favorece el `done` aparte de dejar de utilizar algo obsoleto, es que el espera que se haga la petición y luego con los datos actualiza tu vista, y el `fail` te ayuda para saber si fallo la petición , probastes el `fail`

Comment: Me van a matar... ya esta realizado! mi error era que estaba poniendo mi script en nuevos ámbitos y no estaba declarada mi variable `base_url`. Aquí me di cuenta cunado entre a la consola y eso porque me dijo @Sr1871. También agradezco tu respuesta @Travv. Realmente ambas respuesta son acertadas... No se aquí debería ponerle los puntos ya que los dos me lo advirtieron desde un principio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error es usar el sucesss para eso, hay una diferencia entre el sucess y el done

para que funcione tienes que hacer

```
$.ajax({
     url: base_url + "clientes/Clientes_controller/contrato_view",
     type:"POST",
     dataType:"html",
     data:{id:valor_IDcontrato},
}).done(function(data) {
     $("#modal_contrato .modal-body").html(data);
});
```

documentación de [done](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

[diferencia entre success y done (en ingles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847829/what-is-difference-between-success-and-done-method-of-ajax)

Comment: Estoy en proceso de leer la documentación... Pero al menos cambiando a `done` sigue sin funcionar... Gracias por la información.

Answer (score 2):

En la petición `$.ajax()` , el `dataType` que especificas es **html**, y en el `data` le pasas un **json**, borra el `dataType` o ponle `json`, que es el tipo de datos que envías.

Nota: Ten en cuenta lo que recibes en el data de la función success del `ajax` , si recibes igual un objeto, con la información seria `data.valiarbleConInformacion`

Te recomiendo utilizar `.done` , ya que a partir de jquery 1.5 , las peticiones `ajax` se implementan siguiendo la interfaz de promesas, utilizando sus métodos y propiedades,[ver mas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98884/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-success-y-done), en este caso seria como indican, retificando lo del **http**:

```
$.ajax({
     url: base_url + "clientes/Clientes_controller/contrato_view",
     type:"POST",
     data:{id:valor_IDcontrato}
}).done(function(data) {
     $("#modal_contrato .modal-body").html(data);
});
```

Esta solución seria correcta, ya que esperaría que se realizara la petición con éxito, y luego obtendría los datos para ser mostrados.

Al igual que utilizas el `.done` , puedes utilizar el `.fail()` para saber si la petición esta fallando e ir descartando, ejemplo:

```
function xhr_get(url) {

  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: mostrarImagenCargando
  })
  .always(function() {
    // Por ejemplo removemos la imagen "cargando..."
  })
  .fail(function() {
    // Manejar errores
  });

}
```

Comment: Ya lo intente como me dice, pero, no. No quedo :(

Comment: actualice la respuesta, prueba lo que te recomiendo para que sepas con mas detalles que sucede con tu petición