# ¿Como llamar funciones de PHP a JavaScript y mandar el valor a un input de un Modal?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, phpmyadmin, php7

Estoy generando folios personalizados, ya logre generar el folio que requiero, Pero tengo una duda, Como puedo hacer, que cuando seleccione una opción llame a mi método para que genere el folio al cual corresponde y lo pueda enviar al input de folio. El primer ejemplo es una prueba que realice par visualizar que realmente me genere los folios. Espero me pueda orientar

[image: Modal]

aquí pongo una parte de mi código selected

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-form-label">Cuadrilla</label>
                                <select name="cuadrilla" id="cuadrilla" class="form-control" required>
                                    <option selected>Seleccione una opción</option>
                                    <option value="1">Cuadrilla de Operación Ciudad</option>
                                    <option value="2">Cuadrilla de Operación Megasistema</option>
                                    <option value="3">Cuadrilla de Drenajes</option>
                                    <option value="4">Cuadrilla de Tomas tapadas</option>
                                    <option value="5">Cuadrilla de Cloración</option>
                                    <option value="6">Cuadrilla de Bacheo</option>
                                    <option value="7">Cuadrilla de Contratos</option>
                                </select>
```

Aquí dejo la función de mis folios

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['funcion']) && !empty($_POST['funcion'])) {
    $funcion = $_POST['funcion'];

    switch ($funcion) {
        case 'operacion_ciudad':
            function Codigo_Operacion_Ciudad($strength)
            {
                //$strength = 10;
                $input = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
                $input_length = strlen($input);
                $random_string = 'COPC-';
                for ($i = 0; $i < $strength; $i++) {
                    $random_character = $input[mt_rand(0, $input_length - 1)];
                    $random_string .= $random_character;
                }
                return $random_string;
            }
            break;

        case 'operacion_mega':
            function Codigo_Operacion_Mega($strength)
            {
                $input = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
                $input_length = strlen($input);
                $random_string = 'COPM-';
                for ($i = 0; $i < $strength; $i++) {
                    $random_character = $input[mt_rand(0, $input_length - 1)];
                    $random_string .= $random_character;
                }
                return $random_string;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Estoy realizando esta función JavaScript, pero no sé cómo realizar que cuando seleccione una opción, llame mi función y envíe el valor al input folio. Alguien que me pueda orientar

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#cuadrilla").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "../controladro/folio.php",
      method: "POST",
      async: false,
      data: { funcion: "operacion_ciudad" },
      dataType: "json",
      dataSrc: "",
      success: function (respuesta) {},
    });
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: "../controladro/folio.php",
    method: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: { funcion: "operacion_mega" },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (respuesta) {
      //Accion diferente al otro AJAX
    },
  });
});
```

[image: Folio no mostrado]

Genera el folio correctamente, pero no lo muestra en el input de mi ventana modal

Este es el código de mi folio de mi PHP

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-form-label">Folio:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="folio" disabled>
                                
                            </div>
```

Comment: Con `fetch` o `ajax` lo puedes conseguir.

Comment: Tienes algun ejemplo?

Comment: En la comunidad encuentras múltiples ejemplos. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax

Comment: @DjCrazy lo estoy intentando realizar, pero ya me quede trabado.

Comment: ¿En qué te quedaste trabajado? ¿Cuál es el error?  Revisa la consola del navegador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma fácil de hacerlo es procesando la información en tu php como lo tienes, pero para que Ajax pueda tomar los datos debes imprimirla con un **echo** en vez del **return** y enviar el value del input seleccionado para que ejecute el *case especifico*.

```html
<?php
//COMPROBAMOS LA VARIABLE ENVIADA DESDE AJAX "OPERACION"
if (isset($_POST['operacion'])) {
    $funcion = $_POST['operacion'];
    
    switch ($funcion) {
        case '1': //operacion_ciudad
            $strength = 10;
            $input = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            $input_length = strlen($input);
            $random_string = 'COPC-';
            
            for ($i = 0; $i < $strength; $i++) {
                $random_character = $input[mt_rand(0, $input_length - 1)];
                $random_string .= $random_character;
            }
            echo $random_string;
        break;

        case '2'://operacion_mega
            $strength = 10;
            $input = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            $input_length = strlen($input);
            $random_string = 'COPM-';
            for ($i = 0; $i < $strength; $i++) {
                $random_character = $input[mt_rand(0, $input_length - 1)];
                $random_string .= $random_character;
            }
            echo $random_string;
        break;
    }
}else{
    echo "NO LLEGA NADA";
}
?>
```

Posterior a eso, cuando Ajax ejecute la petición correctamente, en el succes tomaremos la **data** (respuesta PHP), que en este caso la denominaste **respuesta** y quedaría así:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //DETECTAMOS CAMBIOS EN EL SELECT CUADRILLA
  $("#cuadrilla").on('change', function() {
    //OBTENEMOS EL VALOR SELECCIONADO DEL SELECT
    $("#cuadrilla option:selected").each(function() {
      //GUARDAMOS ESE VALOR EN UNA VARIABLE, QUE PUEDE SER 1,2,3 ETC, SEGUN EL VALUE DE TU SELECT
      var operacion = $(this).val();
      console.log(operacion),
        $.ajax({
          //VERIFICA SI ES CONTROLADOR O CONTROLADRO, PUEDE QUE ESTE MAL TU RUTA
          url: "controlador/folio.php",
          method: "POST",
          //ENVIAMOS EL VALOR DE LA VARIABLE
          data: {
            operacion: operacion
          },
          //ACCIÓN ANTES DE ENVIAR
          beforeSend: function() {
            //PINTAMOS EN EL ELEMENTO HTML CON ID FOLIO LA DATA DE PHP
            alert('Enviando...');
          },
          success: function(respuesta) {
            //PINTAMOS EN EL ELEMENTO HTML CON ID FOLIO LA DATA DE PHP
            $('#folio').val(respuesta);
          },
          //ACCIÓN SI OCURRE UN ERROR
          error: function() {
            alert('No se pudo enviar');
          },
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Se puede hacer todo en una sola función como el ejemplo que te puse, no comprendí bien para que querías hacer dos o mas peticiones AJAX, ese es un ejemplo de como puedes hacerlo, adapta tu código según tus necesidades y agrega los case faltantes. Espero te sirva.

NOTA: YA FUNCIONA, MODIFIQUE EL PHP Y JS, NO CREO QUE TENGAS MAS INCONVENIENTES, SOLO OBSERVA BIEN LOS CAMBIOS ECHOS PARA QUE SEPAS ENCONTRAR LOS ERRORES, NO SOLO COPIAR Y PEGAR, TAMBIÉN ES INVESTIGAR Y COMPRENDER EL CÓDIGO, ADJUNTE IMÁGENES FUNCIONANDO.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, Gracias por tu ayuda, Tengo una duda, en mi selected de php, tengo que agregar onchangue? ¿Para qué me pueda ejecutar las funciones? Ya integre el código, pero no me muestra los folios.

Comment: Ingrese el código, pero no me muestra ninguna acción, no sé si en mi selected tenga que agregar changue

Comment: No amigo, solo en tu html en la parte del head, agrega el escript js donde tienes esa función y la librería de JQuery. Otro error puede que sea la ruta a la que envías por Ajax, te puse un comentario para que lo revisaras, no necesitas agregar nada en tu input. Otra forma de ver el error es inspeccionar el elemento en tu navegador y en el apartado consola ver los errores.

Comment: Ya integré el JS, también compuse la ruta, pero no me manda ningún error, pero tampoco me muestra los folios.

Comment: Podemos revisar?

Comment: Mira lo que puedes hacer para saber donde esta el error es:

Comment: Me muestra bien, el Ajax no me manda error, solo que no me manda el folio al input.

Comment: Mira lo que puedes hacer para saber donde esta el error es: 1- agregar "else" en el if de php donde verifica que el dato llegue, esto con un mensaje de "error", si no es ahí, entonces en ajax antes del success agrega beforeSend y después del succes error y su función, así comprobamos si la petición se realizo correctamente.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136599/discussion-between-andres-de-jesus-and-antonio-galicia).

Comment: En la respuesta de AJAX me muestra operación "1" Lo cual es correcto, porque está llamando a mi función folio.php, pero no me muestra nada en mi input.

Comment: Creo que el error es de aquí //PINTAMOS EN EL ELEMENTO HTML CON ID FOLIO LA DATA DE PHP
          $('#folio').html(respuesta);

Comment: Amigo he modificado la respuesta y el código de los scripts, échale un ojo y me dices si ya funciona, adjunte también imágenes de prueba. Suerte.

Comment: Gracias, ya identifiqué el error, Pero ahora quiero que visualices en una imagen que subiré Lo que ocurre, ya funciona correctamente pero esto pasa.

Comment: No habías mencionado que era para un modal, por eso la importancia en la redacción en la pregunta, esto te puede ayudar [ejemplo con modal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126682/cargar-vista-en-un-modal-con-ajax) o genera otra pregunta.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné @Antonio Galicia Muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegro mucho, solo como ultimo, agrega la solución que obtuviste aparte de la mía, para que alguien que tenga la misma duda que tu, pueda encontrar la solución en esta pregunta. Agrégala como otra respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

prueba reescribir el javascript asi:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
    $(function() {
        $("select").keyup(function () {
            $(this).triggerHandler("change");
        });
    });
    
    $('#cuadrilla').change(function () { 
         $.ajax({
          url: "../controladro/folio.php",
          method: "POST",
          async: false,
          data: { funcion: "operacion_ciudad" },
          dataType: "json",
          dataSrc: "",
          success: function (respuesta) {},
        });
    });

});
```