# Before send en AJAX con Jquery 3.0

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estuve leyendo el siguiente post: [¿Cual es la diferencia entre success y done?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98884/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-success-y-done) y me di cuenta que desde la vercion 3.0 de JQuery se utiliza `done-fail-always` donde se que es lo que hace cada uno, pero anteriormente a esto se usaba `beforeSend` que la verdad lo veo muy util ya que se ejecuta antes de enviar, pero con lo que "he visto" ya no hay esta opcion.

Entonces con lo anterior dicho `done-fail-always` ¿Hay un metodo parecido a  `beforesend`?

Esto lo quiero ya que tengo un alert de carga y cabria perfectamente ahi antes de enviar la solicitud pero lo que hago para solucionar eso es poner dicha funcion antes de ejecutar el ajax

Codigo que tengo:

```
SweetCarga.fire({ title: 'Cargando...'}); //Este es el alert que quiero mostrar en el BeforeSend()
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data
}).done(function(data) {
    //Funcion
}).fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //Funcion
});
```

**EDIT-01:** Leyendo mas a profundidad me di cuenta que `done-fail-always` son metodos de promesas, tambien existen `then-when` pero por lo que quiero hacer no hay un metodo especifico

Comment: El último párrafo se explicaría perfectirijillo con el código que mencionas, en vez de intentar describirlo. :)

Comment: @Alfabravo De hecho es muy simple, pero de igual forma lo pondre

Comment: @Alfabravo listo

Comment: aun puedes utlizar `beforeSend` porque dices que existia?

Comment: @Bryro cierto lo editare, pero lo que quiero es utilizarlo con `done-fail-always`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como `AJAX` es un metodo asincrono la solucion que le di fue encerrarlo en una promesa para poder obtener lo que quiero, de la siguiente forma:

```
function AJAX(url,params)
{
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
    SweetCarga.fire({ title: 'Cargando...'});
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data
    }).done(function(data) {
        //Funcion
    }).fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //Funcion
    });
  });
}
```

Aunque en si estoy haciendo lo que dije "Poner la funcion antes del Ajax", como esta encerrado en una promesa lo veo eficiente, ya que puedo llamarlo asi:

```
AJAX(url,param).then(function (data) {
  //Funcion
});
```

Aunque me gustaria que hubiera alguna manera de no hacer eso y defrente colocarlo en el AJAX

Comment: También puedes utilizar los eventos `ajaxStart` y `ajaxStop` para mostrar y ocultar el loader. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

aun puedes utlizar beforeSend porque dices que existia?

puedes utilizarlo como deses o todas las opciones si deseas

ejemplo:

```js
$.ajax({
type: 'get',
url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=5",
dataType: 'json',
beforeSend: function() {
  console.log("beforesend")
},
success: function(data) {
   console.log("data with success:");
   console.log(data)
},
error: function(xhr) { 
  console.log("error")
},
complete: function() {
     console.log("complete");
},
}).done(function (data) {
console.log("data with done:");
console.log(data);
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
   console.log("fail");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No habia visto eso, combinarlo, pero lo que dije fue segun a la respuesta de la preunta que puse, "Las devoluciones de llamada se eliminan a partir de jQuery 3.0"

Comment: Ademas de que en su documentacion dice lo mismo https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#ajax

Comment: por eso te coloque la ultima version `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
` para que veas que aun estan presente.

Comment: Si pero estoy utilizando la 3.0 como puse en el titulo, aunque en si creo que lo cambiare a la 3.5 si no afecta en nada, ya que tengo un proyecto con esa vercion

Comment: bueno en este caso, tu problemas es mayor a un simple beforeSend `https://blog.jquery.com/2016/09/22/jquery-3-1-1-released/` recomiendo actualizar ya que las nuevas versiones son totalmente compatibles...