# ¿cómo mostrar un span de usuario o contraseña incorrecto con ajax-jquery antes de redirigir a otra pagina con php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, login, headers

¡Que tal!
Estoy implementando el envío de un formulario login con ajax-jquery. La idea es que los datos enviados sean a través de ajax a un archivo php el cual se encarga de hacer la consulta a la BD de manera que, si el usuario o contraseña son incorrectos se muestre un span en el index advirtiéndolo, el proceso funciona también únicamente con php por si algún usuario tiene desactivado los scripts no deje de funcionar el login, el tema aquí es que en la validación por php me redirige al index en caso de un dato equivocado, pero lo hace antes de mostrar el span con la advertencia, de forma que el span no es visible ¿alguna manera de como hacer que se muestre primero el span y después redirigir? ¿o de solamente mostrar el span? ¿o alguna otra idea?

Anexo parte del código:

Código del formulario del index:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6" id="formGroup">
   <form action="login.php " method="POST" name="loginAdm" id="formIndex">
        <label for="formGroup"> Iniciar sesión </label>
        <div class="form-group" >
            <label class="error" for="user" id="user_error" > <b> Por favor ingresa tu usuario: </b></label>
            <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Usuario de administrador" class="form-control" id="user" required>
            <label class="error" for="pass" id="pass_error"><b> Por favor ingresa tu contraseña: </b></label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña" class="form-control" id="pass" >
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="loginSubmit" id="submit">
        </div>
   </form> 
<div id="result"></div>
```

codigo jquery ajax:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  
   $('.error').hide();
  $('#submitAdm').click(function(){
    
    var username=$("#user").val();
    var password=$("#pass").val();
    
    var dataString = 'user='+username+'&pass='+password;
    if($.trim(username).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "login.php",
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          beforeSend: function(){ $("#submit").val('Connecting...');},
          success: function(data){
            if(data){
              $("body").load("vistaLogin.php").hide().fadeIn(1500).delay(6000);
            }else{
              $("#submitAdm").val('Ingresar')
              $("#result").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Usuario o contraseña incorrecta ");
            }
          }
        });

    }
      return false;
  });


});
```

Codigo php login:
El header comentado dentro del else es el que si se descomenta redirige al index si algún dato es incorrecto, esto lo hace siempre, por lo que el span no se ve :c
Y si está comentado pero sucede el caso que los scripts estén desactivados y algun dato es incorrecto, se queda pasmado en el archivo login.php :c

```
//login
if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['user']);
    $pass = strip_tags($_POST['pass']);
    if (strlen(trim($username)) > 1 && strlen(trim($pass)) > 1) {
        $data = $consulta->loginConsult($username, $pass);
        if ($data) {
            header("Location:".URL_VISTALOGIN."");
        }else{
            //header("Location:".URL_INDEX."");
        }
    } else {
        header("Location:".URL_INDEX."");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Un saludo a todos!

He vuelto a dejar la solución para futuros compañeros desarrolladores php.

Siguiendo la idea de @Artes quien respondió a mi pregunta cambié el fragmento del código jquery usando las funciones .fail y .done para manejar las acciones que hará ajax según si el usuario y contraseña son correctos o no (estos cambios no son necesarios para solucionar el problema, pero es una mejor practica )

Para ello agregué la configuración para el tipo de dato que ajax espera del servidor `( dataType: 'xml' )`

Ademas de agregar el ajax a una función nombrada loginIndex que es llamada después de una validación de los inputs de username y paswword.

Codigo jQuery Actualizado:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.error').hide();
  $('#submit').click(function(){
    
    var username=$("#user").val();
    var pass=$("#pass").val();
    
    var dataString = 'user='+username+'&pass='+password;

    function loginIndex(dataString){
      return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'xml',
        beforeSend: function(){ $("#submit").val('Conectando...');},
      })

      
      .fail(function(){
        $("#submit").val('Reenviar');
        $("#result").html("<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'><strong>Usuario o contraseña incorrecto</strong> Intentalo de nuevo.<button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'></button></div>");
      })

      .done(function(){
        $("body").load("vistaLogin.php").hide().fadeIn(1500).delay(2000);
      })
    }



    if($.trim(username).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0){
      back=loginIndex(dataString);
    }
    return false;

  });


});
```

**Aquí la parte importante (y que podía solucionar desde un principio)**
Lo que hacia el archivo login.php era recibir los datos y con un header redireccionar siempre sin mostrar el span o alert, por lo que al poner un tiempo para redireccionar y después dar instrucción de retornar lo soluciona

> header("Refresh:0; URL=".URL_VISTALOGIN." ");

Esto aplicado únicamente cuando cumple condición de ser usuario y contraseña correctos

Codigo login.php actualizado:

```
//login
    if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
        $username = strip_tags($_POST['user']);
        $pass = strip_tags($_POST['pass']);
        if (strlen(trim($username)) > 1 && strlen(trim($pass)) > 1) {
            $data = $consulta->loginConsult($username, $pass);
            if ($data) {
                header("Refresh:0; URL=".URL_LOGIN." ");
                return true;
                exit();
            }else{
                header("Location:".URL_INDEX."");
                exit();
            }
        }else{
            header("Location:".URL_INDEX."");
            exit();
        }
    }
```

De igual manera, si algún lector encuentra una solución más optima para este problema es bienvenido!
Agradecimientos a @Artes

Answer (score 0):

No estoy muy seguro como funciona el código PHP, pero con el JavaScript podrías implementar un `setTimeout` en el `load` para que así puedas mostrar el `span` por el tiempo que quieras.

Answer (score 0):

bienvenido a StackOverflow; viendo tu código en la llamada ajax estás validando la `(data)`, es decir que la data exista, no que la respuesta se correcta o no.
Si estás usando jquery 3+ la librería recomienda usar funciones `.done()` o `.fail()`, te dejo una referencia por si gustar leerla. [done, fail](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98884/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-success-y-done).
En base a esto me parece que la petición debería ser debería de ser.

```
 success: function(data){
        $("body").load("vistaLogin.php").hide().fadeIn(1500).delay(6000);
 }, 
 error: function(){
  /*tu logica si la petición falla*/
 }
```

Sin embargo también me queda una duda en tu **php**, en esta sección en particular,

```
 if ($data) {
        header("Location:".URL_VISTALOGIN."");
    }else{
        //header("Location:".URL_INDEX."");
        /*retornar algo a tu ajax, podria ser un */
        echo json_encode(['respuesta' => 'fallo']);
        //o un error cualquiera.
    }
```

Deberías retornar algo en tu `else`, la cual seria la respuesta de tu `error` en AJAX y en base a ese error hacer tu lógica de mostrar el span, o en su defecto y como está tu lógica, validar el valor de `data`, es decir,

```
   if(data = 'respuesta de error'){
   /*la lógica de tu error*/
   }
```

Saludos.