# generar un post con un ajax y posteriormente enviar otro ajax con post a otra

Tags: ajax

Buen día estoy intentando realizar dos ajax el primero envia datos y genera una inserción, esa parte ya esta controlada, pero no se como ingresar un segundo ajax para enviar otro post a un archivo de impresión térmica, les comparto el código:

```
function calcCredits(){
          /* variables from inputs */
          var last_credit= parseInt(document.getElementById("studentcredits").value);
          var namesec= document.getElementById("studentqr").value;
          var credits= parseInt(document.getElementById("money").value);
          var total_pay = credits * 35;
          var ttl_credits = last_credit + credits;


          $.ajax({
      /* Se envian datos por POST a PHP */
          url:'addcredits.php',
          type:'post',
          data:{namesec:namesec,credits:credits},         
          }).then((response) => {
/*se intenta enviar post a archivo de impresion*/
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ticket.php',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(response){

                        alert('Printing....');
                }
            }); 
          });
      }
```

si raliza la insercion de datos pero la impresion no, aunado a esto no se como ver el porceso en el que se rompe , el debug d ejavascript para ver q esata sucediendo.

Comment: Hay alguna razon especifica para que en tu primer llamada a ajax uses promesas?, porque no usas el callback `success` o `done`como lo estas haciendo en tu segunda peticion  ajax?, tal vez  pueda guiarte. Pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98884/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-success-y-done

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que quieres enviar el **response** del primer Ajax a un segundo?, si es así, en tu primer Ajax en el **succes** ejecutas una segunda función enviando como parámetro el response, en esa segunda función con el parámetro recibido haces una segunda petición, esa seria una forma.

Comment: Perdonen soy nuevo en esto, he revisado lo que me comentaron pero al parecer tampoco es lo que busco, el primer ajax envia info a un archivo php el cual hace un insert, eso esta bien, ahora el segundo ajax que quiero utilizar es para poder enviar la misma info que tengo en el primero a otro archivo php, esto lo deje asi solo para hacer una prueba y ver si imprimia en pantalla pero no lo hace