# Limpiar formulario después de un envío $_POST en PHP

Tags: php

Saludos y mil gracias por responder.
Tengo un código con un botón que elimina datos de una tabla mysql, la pregunta que me surge es: Como puedo hacer para que después que elimine, limpie el formulario en el que estoy trabajando, ya intente redireccionando y también intente hacer un input tipo reset y no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Estoy trabajando con HTML 5, Bootstrap, php, MySQL.

```
case 'eliminar':
         try {
             $sql  = "DELETE FROM cuentas WHERE id=:id";
             $consulta = $conexionBD->prepare($sql);
             $consulta->bindParam(':id', $id);
             $consulta->execute();
             echo '<script language="javascript">
             alert("Cuenta Eliminada Exitosamente...");
               </script>';
             break;
         } catch (\PDOException $lista) {
             echo '<script language="javascript">
                 alert("Lo sentimos, a ocurrido un error...");
               </script>';
         }
         break;
```

Comment: esto te sirve? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/574484/c%c3%b3mo-resetear-este-formulario/574485#574485

Comment: Ya lo había visto, pero no es lo que busco, de todos modos te agradezco mucho.

Comment: entonces qué es lo que quieres lograr hacer?